# Received spam, leak of email addresses?

Tags: support, user-accounts, spam, email

I recently noted several incoming spam emails, which were sent to email addresses I exclusively used on Stack Exchange sites (StackOverflow.com and SuperUser.com)

I used different email addresses for those two sites, and I'm pretty sure I used the addresses on these sites only, never used them for anything else.

Is it possible that Stack Exchange leaked some user email addresses, which are now used by spammers?

Comment: What's your email address?

Comment: You have an 8 year old stack overflow account. At one point, years ago, email hashes were included in the data dumps. Are you using the same address now as you did 8 years ago?

Comment: @random - I've just checked their SO account and it's something that spammers could fairly easily construct.

Comment: Yes, it's the same address as years ago. What bothers me that I received only mails on addresses associated to my accounts. So if someone guessed, I suppose I should have received mails on other email accounts as well, which didn't happen

Comment: Your Superuser and Stackoverflow accounts are merged.  As point out email hashes were in data dumps, and Gravator had a problem also, you should chnage your email addresses

Comment: Btw, as an aside, if your mail provider supports it (e.g. Gmail and many other large ones), you can append arbitrary tags to your email address with a "+" sign (e.g. `myemail+stackexchange@example.com` if your address is `myemail@example.com`). I do this as a rule so I can identify where spam sourced its email addresses from. It's not fool-proof, of course, spammers can strip the tags before sending, but it's caught a few issues in the past (not here, but in general). See also [email subaddressing](https://www.google.com/search?q=email%20subaddressing).

Comment: Note btw that the old Gravatar issue wasn't particularly tiny. If that were the source you certainly wouldn't be the only person that happened to. If you like your gravatar image, I'm pretty sure you can cut gravatar out of your chain in the future by downloading the image then reuploading it as an actual image, then changing your email.

Comment: You can also just regenerate it, that's what I did, and only mention that issue because it's an alternative explaination to what might have happened

Comment: @JasonC I'm just doing that, that's how I found out where the emails could have been leaked.

Comment: [Possibly related.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291029/unsolicited-email-from-a-startups-user-my-email-is-not-public)